# solving this 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could someone help me with this problem?

I have a second order ODE as such:

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\beta \frac{dx}{dt} = f(t) $$

I am not sure how to solve this linear ODE, was hoping someone could help.

does this look right?

$$e^{\beta t} \frac{dx}{dt}+\beta e^{\beta t}x=e^{\beta t} g(t)  $$

$$ \frac{d}{dt}( xe^{\beta t} )= e^{\beta t} g(t) $$

$$xe^{\beta t} = \int e^{\beta t} g(t)  $$

$$x(t) = \frac{\int e^{\beta t} g(t)}{e^{\beta t}}  $$

Comment: Is $\beta$ a constant? If so, this is a linear DE.

Comment: Yes $\beta$ is a constant

Comment: There are few suspicious moments in your solution: 1) you've forgot to define $g(t)$ (@David-Cardozo pointed that several times); 2) your $x(t)$ in the beginning and at the end definitely aren't the same functions; 3) so you have to fix the transition from initial second-order linear ODE to the first-order linear ODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for another answer, the problem to solve is:
$$
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\beta \frac{dx}{dt} = f(t)
$$
let us use the substituion, $r(t) = \dfrac{dx}{dt}$ so that  and $\dfrac{dr}{dt} = \dfrac{d}{dt} \dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} $. We have then:
$$
\dfrac{dr}{dt} + \beta r = f(t) 
$$
and this is a first order ode that can be solved using the integration factor method

Comment: Isnt this what I did in the Question?

Comment: Integration factor $ \mu(t) = e^{ \int \beta dt}$. and the solution will be $ r(t) = \dfrac{ \int \mu(t) f(t) dt }{\mu(t)}$.

Comment: Right, look at the end of the question statement. I did this. What is wrong with it?

Comment: In your question you assumed the solution, here we don't assume any special form of the solution.

Comment: How did I assume solution? I used integrating factor

Comment: and at the end we also need to solve $ \dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{ \int \mu(t) f(t) dt }{\mu(t)} $

Comment: How do we solve that?

Comment: Well just $ x(t) = \int ( \dfrac{ \int \mu(t) f(t) dt }{\mu(t)} ) dt$

Comment: So you are saying that is the answer?

Comment: Yes, so don't forget to define $ \mu(t) $

Comment: that is just $exp(\beta t)$ right?

Comment: $\mu(t) = e^{ \int \beta dt} $

Comment: right, which equals what i had

Comment: don't forget if this is the answer, please reflect on choosing "this is the answer". Thanks.

Comment: I understand, I just don't know why this is any better than what I already had

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19293/discussion-between-jackson-hart-and-david-cardozo).

Answer (score 2):

Integrate once and we have

$$\frac{dx}{dt} + \beta x = \int_{t_0}^t f(t') \ dt'$$

Call the RHS $g(t)$. Now, do you know how to handle an equation of the sort

$$\frac{dx}{dt} + \beta x = g(t)$$
?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the proper method. Integrating factor maybe?

Comment: Yes, an integrating factor

Comment: What difference I could suggest is to use $p =\dot{x}$ first and do the integrating factor first. But it's taste rather than any better :). +1

Comment: p(t)=$\beta$ right?

Comment: I don't know what notation you're using. But if $p(t)$ is the function that is in front of $x(t)$ then clearly yes. If $p(t)$ is the integrating factor itself then no.

Comment: What? I need to find $\mu$ Just asking if this is also $exp(\beta t)$

Comment: If you mean $p(t)$ as in this MIT lecture, then yes:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVzaX9u6YAE&feature=youtu.be&t=23m40s

Ok, you've edited your comment. Yes, the integrating factor is $\exp(\beta t)$

Comment: @SimonS Can you check my progress in my question?

Comment: Looks right. Now integrate.

Comment: still look right?

Comment: I recommend you watch the lecture fragment I linked to above. Your latest edit is not correct.

Comment: should be right now i think, i forgot an x

Comment: Yes ... now right

Comment: I'm not sure how to integrate RHS, integration by parts will not get either term to disappear?

Comment: You just leave the RHS integral as is. I recommend once more that you watch the lecture fragment; it will make all of this very clear.

Comment: Then what exactly is the solution here? seems weird to leave it like that

Comment: You just need to go one more step: $x(t) = ...$

Comment: take one last look?

Comment: Usually written as $x(t) = e^{-\beta t} \int e^{\beta t} g(t) \ dt$.

Answer (score 1):

To proceed we will first solve the associated homogeneous equation:

$$
\frac{d^2x_h}{dt^2}+\beta \frac{dx_h}{dt} = 0
$$

of course the solutions will be:
$$
x_h(t) = c_1 \cdot e^{\lambda_1}t + c_2 \cdot e^{\lambda_2}t 
$$
Where $ \lambda_{1,2} $ are the solutions of the second degree equation
$$
\lambda^2 + \beta \cdot \lambda = 0 
$$
Then, once you have $ x_h $, you then use variation of parameters (or any annihilator approach) to  find a particular (only one) $ x_p $ that solves:
$$
\frac{d^2x_p}{dt^2}+\beta \frac{dx_p}{dt} = f(t)
$$
and the general solution for: 
$$
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\beta \frac{dx}{dt} = f(t)
$$
is 
$$
x(t) = x_h(t) + x_p(t)
$$

Comment: DO you see a problem with the integration factor method?

Comment: Expanding on the second degree equation we have $ \lambda ( \lambda + \beta) = 0 $, so you have $ \lambda_1 = 0 $ and $ \lambda_2 = -\beta$, so your is $x_h = c_1 + c_2 \cdot e^{-\beta t} $ and the rest will be depending on the $f(t)$ and the method of anihilator or variation of parameters.

Comment: Right, but do you see my solution in original question? What is wrong with that solution?

Comment: Well you are assuming that the solution is of the form $ x(t) = e^{\beta t} $, but observe the solution is of the form $ x(t) = c_1 + c_2 e^{-\beta t} + x_p(t) $, so that you need to change your form of solution otherwise you will never get the answer.

Comment: So you are saying the method is incorrect? Im not sure how to change the form to match what you have.

Comment: Could you expand this answer?