# ordinary differential equation solving

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have a diffeq:

I have a nonlinear Diffeq:

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\beta \frac{dx}{dt}+\varepsilon e^{- \lambda x} = f(t) $$

where $f(t)$ is a function that is known, and $\beta$ and $\lambda$ are constants that are known. Also, we know that $\epsilon$ is a constant parameter that is small.

I first need to obtain the zero order solution $x_0$, before finding the first order solution $x_1$

The first thing that I need to do is to use asymptotic expansions to obtain solutions of order $\epsilon=0$ and (TYPO)

Note that general solution for f(t) that will have two unknown constants.

UPDATE: After the first order term is solve, it needs to be plugged back in. The exponential needs to be linearized and things should start cancelling out. I am not sure how to do this, I just know this is what needs to be done.

UPDATE2: Correction, $\epsilon = 1$ was a typo. It should be $\epsilon^1$
I need to find a solution in the form:

$$x(t)=x_0(t)+\epsilon^1x_1(t)+\epsilon^2x_2 (t) + ... $$

So initially, $\epsilon$ needs to be set to 0 in order to obtain $x_0$. To find $x_1$, I need $\epsilon^1$

UPDATE3: I know now that I need to plug:

$$x=x_0+\epsilon_1x_1 $$ back into the original equation

Thus:

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(x_0+\epsilon_1x_1) + \beta\frac{d}{dt}(x_0+\epsilon_1x_1)+\epsilon \times exp(-\lambda(x_0+\epsilon_1x_1))  $$

Then

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x_0+\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\epsilon_1x_1+\beta \frac{d}{dt}x_0 +\beta \frac{d}{dt}\epsilon_1 x_1+\epsilon \times exp(-\lambda x_0))+\epsilon \times exp(-\lambda \epsilon_1 x_1)$$

I think then the $x_0$ terms may cancel with f(t) or something like that? It may be some sort of approximation.

I still need to linearize the exponential. Any help is appreciated.

Update4: Taking the solution a little but further...

We know that:

$$\frac{d^2x_0}{dt^2}+\beta \frac{dx_0}{dt} = f(t) $$

So, those terms all cancel. And now we have:
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\epsilon_1x_1 +\beta \frac{d}{dt}\epsilon_1 x_1+\epsilon \times exp(-\lambda(x_0+\epsilon_1x_1))=0$$

But we dont want $\epsilon^2$ terms, to part of the exponential goes away as well.

We are left with:
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\epsilon x_1 +\beta \frac{d}{dt}\epsilon x_1+\epsilon \times exp(-\lambda x_0)=0$$

Where we know $x_0$. This now means that the exponential is no longer a function of arbitrary x.

$$\frac{d^2x_1}{dt^2} +\beta \frac{dx_1}{dt}+ e^{-\lambda x_0}=0$$

Where we know $x_0$. Should I use method of undetermined coeffs?

Comment: Is this exactly how the problem is stated? I would expect $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} +\beta \frac{dx}{dt}+ e^{-\lambda t}=0$$ where $x(0) = x_0$

Comment: The original function had $e^ {\lambda x}$ However, I have solved the solution to this point. More details can be found:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055041/nonlinear-differential-equation-question

Comment: In that case, please edit your question to state the original problem and then show the work you did to get to where you are now. As your question is currently stated, I have a hunch of how you can solve this but am unsure without more information.

Comment: @graydad What hunch did you have on how to solve this?

Comment: @graydad Note that I left out the solution for solving $x_0$ Note that this has been solved and is thus, known

Comment: Ah, I see this is a nonlinear problem now. That makes my hunch incorrect. I have worked a problem like this before, except I had to find the value of $\varepsilon$ that resulted in a change in solution. The answer to that was $\varepsilon = 0.25$, but I doubt that will help you here.

Comment: @graydad Why cant the exponential just be moved to the right hand side and solved with undetermined coeffs

Comment: I don't know that it can't; I just know that nonlinear systems are almost always impossible to solve.

Comment: I am just asking if I can move exp to RHS and say exp(AX) etc

Comment: since we know $x_0$, does it not turn into a linear ODE?

Comment: I think the fact that this equation contains a second derivative prevents this from being a linear ODE. There is certainly nothing wrong with moving the exponent to the other side! I just can't see a solution at the moment, and I have not encountered problems where you need to find solutions in terms of $\epsilon^1$ and $\epsilon^2$. As much as I would like to help, I don't think I'll be able. I just thought initially it was something I could help with.

Comment: @graydad I don't think the solution will be in terms of $\epsilon$ The epsilons cancel out.

Comment: Surely you have to do epsilon expansion of $t$ also?

Answer (score -2):

[solving this 2nd order ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057739/solving-this-2nd-order-ode)

you solved this kind of 2nd order diff eqn before for x0

consider e^-ramda xo as a f(t)

the solution will be similar

Comment: So method of integrating factor? Could you expand on your solution?

Comment: yes integrating factor,
 just substitute e^ramda*xo to f(t) in your solution of x0

Comment: could you show this in your answer with LATEX?

Comment: x1=∫▒(∫▒〖〖-e〗^(-ramda*x0) e^(beta*t) 〗 dt)/e^(beta*t)  dt

Comment: this is a same form of your x0 solution and this x1 is in terms of x0